# How does the Dsun.java2d.trace work

Tags: java, performance, java-2d, system-properties

I have seen [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html) already. I am trying to understand how does Dsun.java2d.trace works when applied to a system or application. When does these flags get set? The link says on less-than-desirable performance,can we have an example or the charecter of performances it may deal with? Where can we find the trace if we set it like

```html
-Dsun.java2d.trace=log
```

and i also tried

```html
-Dsun.java2d.trace=log,out=mylogfilename.log
```

but i couldn't find any of the traces in the specified file too. Please correct me if there is anything wrong in my undersatnding or the way i am using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-D** swithces allows to set the properties to be attached with the system properties for java 2d.

```
-Dsun.java2d.trace
```

the above property is used for setting the logging properties for the log level and how it should be logged. Use the below syntax for the same

```
-Dsun.java2d.trace=log,out:mylogfilename.log
```

Comment: You mean logging properties like the INFO, WARN, ERROR or OFF of log4j? So that means it is better to use log4j rather than using something like this,right?